# Matching repeated groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like this

```
{{ a_name a_description:"a value" another_description: "another_value" }}
```

I want to match `a_name` and all the descriptions and values.

The [regex I'm using right](http://rubular.com/r/FQox0wyhpe) now is

```
{{\s*(?<function>\w+)\s+((?<attr>\w+)\s*\:\s*\"(?<val>\w+?)\"\s*)+}}
```

But that only matches the last group, how can I match all groups? 
I'm using JavaScript if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
var re = /{{ (\w+) (\w+):\"([a-zA-Z_ ]+)\" (\w+): \"([a-zA-Z_ ]+)\" }}/
var out = re.exec('{{ a_name a_description:"a value" another_description: "another_value" }}')
```

`out` will be an array with the matches you need.

If you need to capture a generic number of `key: "value"` pairs, this will help:

```
var str = '{{ a_name a_description: "a value" another_description: "another_value" }}'
var pat = /[a-zA-Z_]+: "[a-zA-Z_ ]*"/gi
str.match(pat)
```

Comment: Ummm but what if I have more than two groups of parameters, in the form of desc:"val", what if i have like 20

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this in 2 parts, first get the name and then the description/value pairs.

```
str = '{{ a_name a_description:"a value" another_description: "another_value" }}';
name = /\w+/.exec(str);

// notice the '?' at the end to make it non-greedy.
re = /(?:(\w+):\s*"([^"]+)"\s*)+?/g;
var res;
while ((res = re.exec(str)) !=null) {
    // For each iteration, description = res[1]; value = res[2];
}
```

**ETA**: You can do it with one regex but it does complicate things:

```
re = /(?:{{\s*([^ ]+) )|(?:(\w+):\s*"([^"]+)"\s*)+?/g;
while ((res = re.exec(str)) !=null) {
    if (!name) {
        name = res[1];
    }
    else {
        description = res[2];
        value = res[3];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think the right way to go with this case is waterfall approach: you first extract the function name, then parse the parameters just by using `split`.

```
var testString = '{{ a_name a_description:"a value" another_description: "another_value" }}';
var parser = /(\w+)\s*([^}]+)/;
var parts  = parser.exec(testString);

console.log('Function name: %s', parts[1]);
var rawParams = parts[2].split(/\s(?=\w+:)/);
var params    = {};
for (var i = 0, l = rawParams.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var t = rawParams[i].split(/:/);
  t[1] = t[1].replace(/^\s+|"|\s+$/g, ''); // trimming
  params[t[0]] = t[1];
}
console.log(params);
```

But I may be wrong. )